# Como printar somente os valores diferentes de 0

Tags: c

Galera, estou com uma dúvida. É possível em C printar somente os valores diferentes de 0.

Um Exemplo:

- Temos as saída: 2.56000, 5.00000, 3.60000 e 27.36800
- E quero que imprima da seguinte forma: 2.56, 5, 3.6 e 27.368

Mas com a impressão rodando em um loop onde só posso colocar

```
printf("%.2f \n");
```

ou

```
printf("%f \n");
```

ou

```
printf("%.1f \n");
```

ou

```
printf("%.3f \n");
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Você sabe que pontos flutuantes tem como objetivo dados científicos, certo? E sabe que 1.0 tem precisão implícita de 5%, enquanto que 1.00000 tem precisão na ordem de 5E-6, certo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode usar o especificador de conversão `%g` para resolver o seu problema:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf( "%g\n",  2.560 );
    printf( "%g\n",  5.000 );
    printf( "%g\n",  3.600 );
    printf( "%g\n", 27.368 );

    return 0;
}
```

Saída:

```
2.56
5
3.6
27.368
```

Comment: Tão simples assim?! Hahaha muito obrigado amigo :D

Answer (score 0):

Assim fica mais fácil pra você printar tudo

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
  float num, num1=2.56000, num2=5.00000, num3=3.60000, num4=27.36800;
  printf("Informe um numero: ");
  scanf("%f",&num;

  while(num!=0){
    printf("%.2f \n",num1);
    printf("%.0f \n",num2);
    printf("%.1f \n",num3);
    printf("%.3f \n",num4);

    printf("Inf. um valor: ");
    scanf("%f",&num);
  }
  return 0;
}
```